# Run sql user Query within Notebook

Tags: databricks, databricks-sql

We would like to schedule sql [Queries](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/user/queries/index.html) to be run and then emailed to a list of email addresses that are not users of databricks. Most BI tools have this feature.

You can [schedule](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebooks-manage.html#schedule-notebook) a Dashboard refreshes and have that emailed to databricks users, however this does not work for us for two reasons:

1. We would like to email out to external users.
2. Only a jpg image of the dashboard is provided, we would want the results in csv.

Is it possible to access the sql Queries saved from a Notebook, run them with the required parameters and then export the results into a csv to be emailed out?